# l3build - Demos - How to use --shell-escape?

Tags: l3build

How can I set `typesetcmds` such as to use `--shell-escape` because my demos use `minted`?

```lua
-- build.lua

module = "bdoc"

sourcefiles      = {"*.sty"}
typesetdemofiles = {"demos/*.tex"}
typesetcmds      = "?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

l3build has option variable for the commandlines used for testing or typesetting

```
checkopts   = checkopts   or "-interaction=nonstopmode"
typesetopts = typesetopts or "-interaction=nonstopmode"
unpackopts  = unpackopts  or ""
```

so if you set

```
checkopts = "--shell-escape"
```

shell escape will be used for tests, or same with `typesetopts` for typesetting the documented sources or other documents.

Comment: This will do. Thanks for everything. I'll try to be quieter the next day. :-)